# Server Sent Events Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, http, server-sent-events

I want to use Server Sent Events in my `WebView` on Android (4.4). The EventSource should connect to a local `Port (5003)` where I have a ServerSocket listening for incoming requests:

```
Socket _socket;

//Creating Server Socket listening on Port 5003
try {
    InetAddress adress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(5003, 50, adress);
    while(true){
        _socket = serversocket.accept();      //Accept incoming request
        Logger.Log.d("SSE","Received Server Sent Event Request);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The JavaScript from my HTML Page:

```
var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:5003/'); 

source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
}, false);

source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
        // Connection was opened.
        console.log('open');
}, false);

source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  var txt;
  switch( event.target.readyState ){
      // if reconnecting
    case EventSource.CONNECTING:
      txt = 'Reconnecting...' + event.target.url;
      break;
      // if error was fatal
    case EventSource.CLOSED:
      txt = 'Connection failed. Will not retry.';
      break;
  }
  console.log(txt);
}, false);
```

The EventSource doesn't connect to my local socket.
Every 3 seconds the onError is called and the EventSource tries to reconnect.

```
I/chromium(15898): [INFO:CONSOLE(24)] "Reconnecting...http://localhost:5003/"
```

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself.

The code is working. I only had to reset my Android device to factory defaults.
Now everything works perfectly.